# What bitcoin address has the most amount of UTXOS available for it to spend?

Tags: utxo-set

I'm not asking what the richest bitcoin address is. That information is easy to find. I'm asking what address has the most amount of UTXOS/inputs available for it to use (whether said inputs are just a few hundred satoshis, doesn't matter). This is just for fun but i'm curious and would like to know this (and also how this information would be found in the first place)

Answer (score -1):

I did not find anyone who did this already so did it myself, but used to signet to have a much smaller data set (signet utxos are 41M, mainnet utxos are 4.6G now)

I used https://github.com/in3rsha/bitcoin-utxo-dump to get the utxos from the ldb to csv format and used some javascript to count the amount of utxos per address

results (addresses are in mainnet format so have to converted first):

top 10 most UTXOs by address on signet

```
address                                    UTXOs
bc1qfwsnqles0ptp6rmwm4nun4q48yd64uedkve4zy 26928
bc1qp0rz5ek3vyj2ahyypjpxj5lhnrg85kcc62hsh2 22296
bc1q6m9uassy9ha3g45d6xdlp3wrpjffhdkfmdn2yw 18292
bc1qsygnet2jdqm8n2p7wmmklp9yel3k7agpezrlw6 17342
bc1qq2mfy24rkf9ddpz2m56rqf2kpsca5wgyvzn39s 14686
bc1qspqw7uvc7qtqlcfu49qr2v6fwp8f3rqke2ctpa 13274
bc1q9s28zh2pu7rk943gmaal6dc7e5gm4kljk45kss 12011
bc1qgwdjvpnw6yhgw2vfmh9kt6xmm66xaphfrpp3sc 11896
bc1qm7tvlpv00x3q3l2ea3zlksy3xqp78ptx0wv2c9 11223
bc1q4q2c7s3gg6tl7m40layvnhep3j2qc7ucq78yum 10984
```

to convert a bech32 address from mainnet to signet (testnet) from:

```
 > bitcoin.address.toBech32(bitcoin.address.fromBech32(v).data, 0, 'tb')
'tb1qfwsnqles0ptp6rmwm4nun4q48yd64uedu2zxeh'
```

you can see on a block explorer that this address has 26928 transactions and 0.00000000 sBTC sent (so all TXOs here are UTXOs)
https://mempool.space/signet/address/tb1qfwsnqles0ptp6rmwm4nun4q48yd64uedu2zxeh

Comment: I'm confused by this answer. You demonstrate that you have all the tools to answer the actual question, but then you instead provide the answer for a different network.

Comment: its an example, everything would take way longer on the mainnet, so i used the way lighter signet as an example